# how do we configure processing server in sitecore 9.3

Tags: xdb, xconnect, processing, aggregation

I know below link but if any link for sitecore 9.3 version?

https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/82/sitecore-experience-platform/en/configure-a-processing-server.html

Answer (score 1):

Starting with Sitecore 9 you don't need to follow that steps.

You just need to install a clean Processing Server from
[https://sitecoredev.azureedge.net/~/media/64425E6F6DD84443824DCCF38CB7541A.ashx?date=20191125T131511](https://sitecoredev.azureedge.net/%7E/media/64425E6F6DD84443824DCCF38CB7541A.ashx?date=20191125T131511). and to configure the connection strings.

In Sitecore 9 it was introduces Sitecore Configuration Roles ( https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/93/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/define-the-server-role.html ) and you need just to set up the role for an instance.

Comment: Any direct steps or Document to setup "Cortex™ Processing Table Storage service",
"Cortex™ Processing Blob Storage service". below link not having full info, "https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/93/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/sitecore-cortex--processing-storage.html"

Answer (score 1):

As Vlad mentioned, you need to use [Sitecore Configuration Roles](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/93/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/define-the-server-role.html) to configure your Content Management and xDB Processing Role.

- In you Content Management Server: in role:define in web.config you will need to set it as 'ContentManagement, Indexing', If you want CM to also be your Reporting role, then set it as 'ContentManagement, Indexing, Reporting'
- In your Content Management Server: you must include reporting.apikey key in the CM connection strings configuration file and set a unique value
- Follow [this guideline for CM server](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/93/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/content-management--cm-.html) to make sure you have configured everything needed for CM
- In Processing server, in role:define in web.config you will need to set it as 'Processing'
- In your Processing Server: you must include the same reporting.apikey key in the connection strings configuration file to be the same as you entered in CM file
- Follow this [guideline for Processing server](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/93/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/xdb-processing.html) to make sure you have configured everything needed

Comment: Any direct steps or Document to setup "Cortex™ Processing Table Storage service",
"Cortex™ Processing Blob Storage service". below link not having full info, "https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/93/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/sitecore-cortex--processing-storage.html"

Comment: You mean this? https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/93/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/scaling-and-configuring-the-sitecore-cortex-processing-engine.html